# Glob search function has no result

Tags: php

i want to search for alle files with the typ *.abc , these abc files are in random folders like:

```
folder/x/y/file.abc
folder/a/file2.abc
...
```

Im trying to find these file with this script

```
function getPreviews($category)
    {
        $directories = glob("$category/*.abc");
        $directory = array();
        foreach($directories as $f)
        {
            $directory[] = str_replace("$category/", "", $f);   
        }
        return $directory;      

    }
```

and i want to do something with each found file, so i do this

```
$abc = getPreviews(import); // import is the folder to search for
    foreach($abc as $abcFile)
        {
            doSomething($abcFile); // im the actual abc file
        }
```

But it does nothing, any ideas why?